# How to make Visual Studio recognize Spring Boot packages and get IntelliSense?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have created a Spring Boot application using Spring Intializr extension of VS Code.
Configuration, Build Tool : maven, Language : Java, groupId : com.example, artifactId : springdemo, Spring boot version : 2.0.3, I have selected 2 dependencies which are Spring MVC and Spring DevTools Core from the dropdown.
Here is the screenshot [Screenshot of the selected dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Cq4.png)
After importing it and opening the folder structure [Project Structure after vs code imports the maven project and opens up the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA5Ak.png)

After this I ran a command

```
chmod 777 mvnw
```

to give permission to the gradle wrapper and after that

```
./mvnw clean install
```

This seems to work fine [logs after the ./mvnw clean install command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LRfg.png)

This is my pom.xml
[My pom.xml contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE3K3.png)

**Here is the difference : My VS Code project does not contain the maven dependencies folder as in case of eclipse and even after install all the packages vs code does not seem to recognize the packages and shows error**
[errors in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh3Ea.png)
This is how my eclipse project structure look like [eclipse project structure contains the maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTCzV.png)

The final result is a running project. The project runs even from vs code by `./mvnw spring-boot:run`

but I am unable to get any kind of IntelliSense from VS Code and although eclipse works but I need to use VS Code. Please help.

Comment: please post actual code and not links to images. This is so that the question remains valid even if the pictures are removed. It also helps any users who want to help answer by allowing them to cut and paste your code vs typing everything by hand.

Comment: You have warnings about missing pom files for plexus--...I think you have some connections issues firewall/proxy etc. delete the directory $HOME/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/  and rebuild on plain command line and check if there are no WARNINGs about missing pom's....

Comment: I tried it out. I deleted those forlders and build the project but of no use. I still get the same errors.